# Whats wrong with this code? <Python 2.7.14>

Tags: python-2.7

```
>>> seq = 'attctgta'
>>> for i in seq[:-2]:
...   if seq[i*3] == 'a' and seq[i*3+1] == 't' and seq[i*3+2] == 't':
...      print 'I'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Basically im just testing to see if the for loop will read the first three letters of seq and print 'I', but im pretty new to this so this seems lik a particularly trivial error.

Can i get some help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you're going through the actual characters in the string, not their indexes, so you have to do something like:

```
try:
    for i, ch in enumerate(seq[:-2]):
        if seq[i*3] == 'a' and seq[i*3+1] == 't' and seq[i*3+2] == 't':
            print 'I'
except IndexError:
    print("Handle me")
```

`enumerate` will allow you to iterate over indexes and chars. But even then you need to catch `IndexError`

Comment: You can omit it if you're 100 % confident your formula never breaks, as Python uses late binding and something may break during the runtime, but will be perfectly ok when coded.

Comment: why is the `IndexError` even there at all? i thought the index in `for i, ch in enumerate(seq[:-2]):` would help that.

Comment: You can also use `for i in range(0, len(seq)):`